# Laravel 5 how to test redirect

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpunit

I have a Laravel 5 app in which one controller action finishes by redirecting to a page outside the Laravel app but on the same domain. Interacting manually with the page works fine, but automating the test with PHPunit doesn't. It keeps trying to load the route and fails with 'headers already sent'.

**Route**

```
Route::post('/trials', [
    'middleware' => ['web'],
    'uses' => 'TrialsController@create'
]);
```

**Controller**

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
  ...
  setcookie( 'etc', $value, time() + 60, '/', "domain.com", true, true) ;
  return Saml2::login('https://store.domain.com');
}
```

**Test**

```
public function testSuccessfulSignup(){

    $this->visit('/signup')
        ->type('test@mail.com', 'mail')
        ->type('Philip', 'first_name')
        ->type('Fry', 'last_name')
        ->press('Signup !') ;
        // ->seePageIs('https://store.domain.com'); doesn't work
        // ->assertRedirectedTo('https://store.domain.com'); doesn't work
}
```

**Error**

```
1) TrialsTest::testSuccessfulSignup
A request to [http://domain.com/trials] failed. Received status code [500].

/private/var/identity/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:196
/private/var/identity/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:80
/private/var/identity/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:114
/private/var/identity/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:554
/private/var/identity/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithPages.php:541
/private/var/identity/tests/TrialsTest.php:154

Caused by
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Util/Printer.php:134)' in /private/var/identity/app/Http/Controllers/TrialsController.php:84
```

## Update

It seems to be related to the web middleware, more specifically the CSRF middleware, interfering with my redirect headers. Specifying `use WithoutMiddleware;` also disables the Session, how can I keep the session but disable CSRF in testing context ?

## Update 2

Regarding close vote: You can see in the test code I have an assertion that it should follow the redirect, what I expect this code to do is follow the redirection beyond the controller action (successfully and not fail) then proceed to do more verifications.

Comment: Please answer your question

Comment: @surfer190 I have no answer, it doesn't work. I think it could be a limitation of the driver or maybe I'm using unit tests to do something they're not designed for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the test or the whole suite in process isolation finally seems to work. This might have been improved with an update of phpunit because it had no effect previously.

Through the command line running:

```
phpunit --process-isolation --filter <method>
```

Or in the phpunit.xml:

```
<phpunit ...
         processIsolation="true"
         stopOnFailure="false">
<testsuites>
</testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Obviously the test code also needs to expect a redirect.

```
$this->doStuff()
     ->assertRedirect($url);
```